# Nativescript error while building the project

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript, sidekick

I'm trying to build a simple project in iOS. While I'm trying to run the project through nativescript sidekick it throws the following error:

```
 [19-03-12 16:25:01.990] Error detected during LiveSync on 
  c02e202ca17e88465b0a195dc79072a9b6ab04a6 for 
  /Users/bvibes/Parthi/ManiBurs. 
 Error: Build failed. Reason is: 'Build failed with error code 2'. 
 Additional information: [00:00:43.341] [WARN]  ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
 The following build commands failed:
```

Ld 
 DerivedData/ManiBurs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ManiBurs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ManiBurs.build/Debug-iphoneos/ManiBurs.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ManiBurs normal armv7
Ld DerivedData/ManiBurs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ManiBurs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ManiBurs.build/Debug-iphoneos/ManiBurs.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ManiBurs normal arm64
(2 failures)
[00:00:43.399] [WARN]  [xcode-build] ld: directory not found for option '-F/tmp/builds/_/457659ebf679bdfd010de0fc82139cb9c95cece2/5.0.3/5.0.0/ManiBurs/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-pro-ui/platforms/ios'
[xcode-build] ld: directory not found for option '-F/tmp/builds/_/457659ebf679bdfd010de0fc82139cb9c95cece2/5.0.3/5.0.0/ManiBurs/platforms/ios/../../node_modules/nativescript-pro-ui/platforms/ios'
[00:00:43.404] [ERROR] [xcode-build] ld: framework not found TNSAutoComplete
[xcode-build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[xcode-build] ld: framework not found TNSAutoComplete
[xcode-build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[00:00:43.637] [ERROR] ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
Ld DerivedData/ManiBurs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ManiBurs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ManiBurs.build/Debug-iphoneos/ManiBurs.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ManiBurs normal armv7
Ld DerivedData/ManiBurs/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ManiBurs/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ManiBurs.build/Debug-iphoneos/ManiBurs.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ManiBurs normal arm64
(2 failures)
'Build failed with error code 2'.

Can anyone help me what the error is ???

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with Sidekick, it didn`t build my none of my projects for Android nor iOS. Try running CLI commands on a clean project (remove all platforms)

```
tns build ios

tns debug ios --watch (--emulator if you are running on simulator)
```